# Arduino emulating a keyboard that has a demultiplexer

Tags: arduino, multiplexer, keyboard

I have a old typewriter which I want to automate with an Arduino. The way I am trying to do it is to replace its keyboard with the Arduino and make the Arduino emulate the keyboard IO.

The keyboard of the typewriter is using a [74154](https://pdf.direnc.net/upload/74154-datasheet.pdf) demultiplexer. The original keyboard setup has:

- 4 pins `mainboard outputs > demultiplexer input`
- 8 pins `demultiplexer output > switches > mainboard inputs`

**My plan so far:**

- remove the keyboard (so also the demultiplexer) completely
- the "8-pins" `demultiplexer output > switches > mainboard inputs`
- replace them with `Arduino digital INPUT pins > mainboard inputs`
- the "4-pins" `mainboard outputs > demultiplexer input`
- replace them with `mainboard outputs >  Arduino analog INPUT pins`
- constantly read data from 4-pins
- depending on their value (0001, 0101, 1011, etc) I would know which row is being "scanned" currently
- if I need to type a character from that row - I would set an appropriate pin from the 8-pins to `OUTPUT LOW` and turn it back to `INPUT` after some milisecons *[1](https://pdf.direnc.net/upload/74154-datasheet.pdf)

**Where I am stuck:**

- If the previous are correct, it would mean that at any time that I "ping" any pin from the 8-pins, it should type on random character
- What happens is - it types 6 specific characters depending on which one from the 8-pins I "ping"
- Extra note: I can set for how long to "ping" the 8-pin and I have tried different values down to 1 ms which does not trigger anything.

Notes:

The 8-pins being set to `INPUT` as initial state and being set to `OUTPUT LOW` for triggering, because of what is mentioned [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/31672/58139) in the second paragraph.

#### Update 1:

Instead of:

> - the "4-pins" `mainboard outputs > demultiplexer input`
>
>   - replace them with `mainboard outputs >  Arduino analog INPUT pins`

I now did

- the "4-pins" `mainboard outputs > demultiplexer input`
- replace them with `mainboard outputs >  Arduino DIGITAL INPUT pins`

Because the values being read with analog input are not absolute at all, so I left the decision making regarding LOW/HIGH input on Arduino's digital input.

I created a sketch of the circuit, which can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_wD8KBaPlxmDAdlcpvnD1HFUdFOpWP84/view?usp=sharing).

Y0 and Y8 connect to modifier buttons (like shift, bold, letter spacing, etc) and IIUC that's why they are also connected through diodes to mainboard input pins 2, 6, 10, 12, 14, and 16. Because the typewriter has "record and re-print" functionality, when it's being done - those modifier buttons are probably disabled so you can not invervene with styling options.

And some **[graphs of the input](https://plot.ly/%7Eartemkloko/1/) that I receive from the mainboard.

Regarding what **phil-g** commented, if you have a look at the graphs you will see that the enable pins are triggered rarely at (random?) moments.

Regarding what **hacktastical** answered, I think it is on the correct path, but I struggle to detect the strobe.

**Current situation:**

I changed my timing library to a more precise one, and set the "input detection" timing to 0.1 ms.

So far I have managed to print a random single character, but at totaly random moments by sending OUTPUT LOW of 1 ms duration to a mainboard input pin. Usually it still prints 6 characters.

**My current questions/problems:**

- How to detect / understand which of my inputs from mainboard signify the strobe?
- Also regarding the strobe, in the bit sequence that **hacktastical** included in the answer, if the outmost right column leads to 6 buttons and one of them is pressed, wouldn't it mean that mainboard would detect LOW when row 0 is scanned, and HIGH all the other times no matter if stobbing or other row being scanned?
- If the previous is correct, doesn't it mean that I should not care about the strobe? As that column will output `1 0 1 1 1 1` to specific mainboard input and all the other columns will not output anything to any mainboard inputs because their buttons are not pressed.
- Since columns are connected to buttons and then to mainboard input, when no buttons are pressed, it means that no current is passed to mainboard inputs. So in this situation I am setting the Arduino pins to INPUT is order to act as disconnected. Does that sound OK?
- My computation of the demultiplexer output shows that also Y10 - Y15 are being triggered quite often, but they are not connected to anything. So why doesn't the mainboard try to trigger only Y0 - Y9?

Comment: Are the enable pins being momentarily pulsed low after establishing the input to the demux? You'd likely do that to avoid spurious outputs while changing the input.

Comment: The circuit sketch link is reporting as broken "Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.".  Why not upload it here?

Answer (score 1):

The demultiplexer is selecting the row. The select inputs probably run continuously, cycling through each row one-by-one. The E0/E1 inputs are probably pulsed so that the outputs show one low bit with a blank in between.

So you get a sequence like this from the mux:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 - idle
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 - row 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 - blank
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 - row 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 - blank
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 - row 2
```

etc.

Seems like you have to do two things:

- follow the row-scanning activity from the host. That is, watch the mux select state
- output the column bit when the correct row ‘comes around’

If they’re strobing the row-select (as I suspect they are) you would also follow that, only outputting the column bit when the row bit is low, otherwise outputting all 1's for column.

As you have access to the mux inputs (4 bits, 16 rows) you can use them directly and reduce the number of Arduino I/O needed from 24 down to 12, or 13 if you need the strobe.